.htaccess redirects without the trailing slashes
I'm at the beginner level when it comes to .htaccess and regular expression.
I'm trying to redo the URL structure on an existing website.
Currently the website has this rule:
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
I want to update the URL redirects so:

There are different categories, like pages, articles, ...
Tell Google that the old URLs pertaining the above rule are redirected to the new categorized URLs (301 redirects)
Make sure there is no trailing slashes at the end of the URLs.

For example:
https://example.com/page.php?name=about-us
will be:
https://example.com/pages/about-us
And tell Google that:
https://example.com/about-us/
will be 301 redirects to:
https://example.com/pages/about-us
Below rules are the most progress that I've made. It adds trailing slashes at the end of the URLs and also I don't know how to do 301 redirects from the above rule to the new structure. I really appreciate any help on this.
RewriteRule ^(pages)/(.*)/$ page.php?name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(articles)/(.*)/$ article.php?name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

To the person who voted to close this question: As per this meta post and this meta post this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

You will need a separate 301 redirect rule to remove trailing / and then internal rewrite rule to show content from the matching .php file.
Have it like this:
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/+$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

# invoke matching .php file
RewriteRule ^(page|article)s/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]


I used your recommendation and I get 404 Not Found. However, below rules seems to work. Am I doing something wrong here?     RewriteRule ^(pages)/(.) page.php?name=$2 [L,QSA,NC].         RewriteRule ^(.)/$ https://example.com/pages/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

404 is due to articles vs article.php (s was not part of .php). I have fixed my rewrite rule, please try again.

Thank you for your help. The code removes the trailing slash, but I still get the 404: "GET /page.php?name=about-us HTTP/1.1" 200 226
"GET /pages/about-us HTTP/1.1" 404 212
"GET /page/about-us HTTP/1.1" 404 211

There was another typo, please try again, it should work now.
